# How to get the Bundle-SymbolicName from an IProject?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm writing a wizard for an eclipse project and want to include another plugin as `Require-Bundle` in the `Manifest.MF`.

I have the `IProject` I want to include, can I access its `Bundle-SymbolicName` without parsing the `Manifest.MF`? Or are there other ways to avoid manual parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IProject` may not represent a plug-in and doesn't have any direct API to get a plug-in id.

You can use the normal Java `Manifest` class to look at the MANIFEST.MF using something like:

```
IProject project = ...

IFile manifestResource = project.getFile(new Path("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
if (manifestResource.exists()) {
    try (InputStream stream = manifestResource.getContents()) {
        Manifest manifest = new Manifest();
        manifest.read(stream);

        String symbolicName = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Bundle-SymbolicName");
    } catch (CoreException | IOException ex) {
       ...
    }
}
```

This code is adapted from code used by Eclipse PDE to look for the plug-in.